# How to calculate 100% (percent) from form inputs with php

Tags: php, math

I'm looking for a proper way to calculate numbers submitted by the user in order to get 100 percent calculation by PHP with some basic validation.

User should be able to enter numbers from 1 to 100, I'm looking for the right way to calculate the sum, for example 25 for `num1` and 50 for `num2` will be equal to 75%, I'm trying to achieve this goal by using something like this form:

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="num1" min="1" max="100">
  <input type="number" name="num1" min="1" max="100">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

With php, I want to do this:

```
<?php 

// Check if form was sent:
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

// Set variables with numbers equal to 0:
$num1 = 0;
$num2 = 0;

// Update the value by the form submitted data:
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];

// Calculation:
// Check if sum is not more than 100%
if($num1+$num2 > 100) {
  echo "Error: more than 100%";
}
if($num1+$num2 < 0.1) {
  echo "Error: less than 1%";
}
?>
```

**Should I use some advanced way for this? Is there a more proper way to do it with PHP?**

*Edited*

Comment: Advanced? More advanced than summing?

Comment: `if($num1+$num2 < 0.1)` should probably be `if($num1+$num2 < 1)`, but aside from that, I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you want to achieve

Comment: I was looking for more ways to check inputs for 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to make things unnecessarily advanced.

If this does the job, leave it at that.

You have a bug here:

```
if($num1+$num2 < 0.1) {
  echo "Error: less than 1%";
}
```

The error will only be shown if the percentage is less than 0.1%, not 1%.

You should change it to the following:

```
if($num1+$num2 < 1) {
  echo "Error: less than 1%";
}
```

In terms of making the code easier to read, you could store the minimum and maximum percentages in variables. You could also make good use of validation.

See the following for an example.

```
$minPercentage = 1;
$maxPercentage = 100;

if (! (isset($_POST['num1']) && is_numeric($_POST['num1']))) {
    echo "Error: num1 should be numeric.";
} elseif (! (isset($_POST['num2']) && is_numeric($_POST['num2']))) {
    echo "Error: num2 should be numeric.";
} else {
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];

    $totalPercentage = $num1 + $num2;

    if ($totalPercentage < $minPercentage) {
        echo "Error: less than {$minPercentage}%";
    } elseif ($totalPercentage > $maxPercentage) {
        echo "Error: more than {$maxPercentage}%";
    } else {
        echo "Total percentage is {$totalPercentage}%";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.